# Xamarin forms check wifi connection on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, wifi, connectivity

I am developing an App that programmatically connects to a hotspot. I need to check if the connection is fully established and for that purpose I use Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity package and the following method:

```
public bool IsWifiConnected()
{
    IEnumerable<ConnectionProfile> profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;
    return profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi);
}
```

Unfortunately, the method returns true from the moment the connection starts to get established and is not fully ready (still shaking hands). Is there a way to check that the connection is fully ready ?

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with Xamarin.Essentials.Connectivity too. Following your example you can do something like this:

```
public bool IsWifiConnected()
{
    var profiles = Connectivity.ConnectionProfiles;
    var access = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

    if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi) && access == NetworkAccess.Internet)
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         return false;
    }
}
```

You can also receive an event when connection profile or network access changes, like this:

```
public class ConnectivityTest
{
     public ConnectivityTest()
     {
         // Register for connectivity changes, be sure to unsubscribe when finished
         Connectivity.ConnectivityChanged += Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged;
     }

     void Connectivity_ConnectivityChanged(object sender, ConnectivityChangedEventArgs  e)
     {
         var access = e.NetworkAccess;
         var profiles = e.ConnectionProfiles;

         if (profiles.Contains(ConnectionProfile.WiFi) && current == NetworkAccess.Internet)
         {
              //Here you can do whatever you want to do when the connection profile is wifi and has internet access.
         }
         else
         {
              //Here you can execute what ever you want if the connection profile is not wifi or has no internet access.
         }
     }
}
```

Please note that all of this examples you can find them in the Xamarin Essentials documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/connectivity?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. my hotspot does not have internet so your test won't work

Comment: I have an issue where I have everything setup but the event doesn't fire when there's a network change. I don't know what I could be missing out. I have my permissions in place

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
If you want to check internet availability when the WIFI network has no internet connection in Forms. You can use `DependencyService` to implement it .Refer the following code.

> in Forms ,create an interface

```
using System;
namespace xxx
{
  public interface INetworkAvailable
  {

    bool IsNetworkAvailable();
  }
}
```

> in iOS project

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Foundation;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(IsNetworkAvailableImplement))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
  public class IsNetworkAvailableImplement:INetworkAvailable
  {
    public IsNetworkAvailableImplement()
    {
    }

    bool INetworkAvailable.IsNetworkAvailable()
    {
        NSString urlString = new NSString("https://captive.apple.com");

        NSUrl url = new NSUrl(urlString);

        NSUrlRequest request = new NSUrlRequest(url, NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData, 3);

        NSData data = NSUrlConnection.SendSynchronousRequest(request, out NSUrlResponse response, out NSError error);

        NSString result = NSString.FromData(data,NSStringEncoding.UTF8);

        if(result.Contains(new NSString("Success")))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Now you can call it in forms ,just like

```
bool isAvailable= DependencyService.Get<INetworkAvailable>().IsNetworkAvailable();

if(isAvailable)
{
  Console.WriteLine("network is available");
}

else
{
  Console.WriteLine("network is unavailable");
}
```